# Execution policy modification

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to run few scripts in different servers which will in turn stop/start the services in many other servers.

I have created a script to change the policy to "Bypass" and run the scripts  and then made the changes back to normal.

```
$LOGPATH = "output.txt"
$system_default_policy = Get-ExecutionPolicy
"Current execution policy $system_default_policy" | Out-File -FilePath $LOGPATH
if ($syste_default_policy -ne 'Bypass') {
    "Changing the execution policy from $system_default_policy to Bypass" | Out-File -FilePath $LOGPATH -Append
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force
    "Successfully changed the execution policy to Bypass" | Out-File -FilePath $LOGPATH -Append
}

### executing the commands to stop/start the services

"Re-writing the changes to default policy" | Out-File -FilePath $LOGPATH -Append
Set-ExecutionPolicy $system_default_policy -Force
"Changed the policy to " + $(Get-ExecutionPolicy) | Out-File -FilePath $LOGPATH -Append
```

However, this seems to be a redundant process in the below case.

1. If the execution policy is already Bypass, then I'm simply resetting it in the last line.
2. I have to run multiple scripts in the same server, so for each script I'm changing it to 'Bypass' and setting it back to original.

Is there any other way where I will run this script only once (to change the execution policy) before executing the scripts and then changing it to original value at the end after running all the scripts.

Comment: the execution policy is not a security thing - it's an anti-accident thing. so there is no real point in having it set to anything other than `AllSigned` or `RemoteSigned`.  i don't see any reason for you to keep switching it on/off ... [*grin*]

Comment: I can't execute the scripts if it's any of the above, hence I'm switching it to Bypass, executing the scripts and then putting it back to RemoteSigned

Comment: Regarding setting it back: You can supply a scope parameter to it. That way you can change it temporarely.

Comment: @BharathKumarReddy - the execution policy does not take effect AFTER you start the script. [*frown*] it is enforced _before_ the start of the script. so ... if you are changing it in the script, you _already_ can execute the script.

Answer (score 4):

The execution policy does only apply to scripts, hence it does not apply to code that is being invoked on the host or passed as an command. There are various ways to do that, some of which are:

`Invoke-Command` from a remote computer.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { 
    # Code 
}
```

`powershell.exe -Command` locally

```
powershell.exe -Command "#code"
```

However, usually the easiest way to run scripts without changing the configuration is

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\yourscript.ps1
```